# Should I convert my Grails domain relations to use Hibernate Bags?

Tags: hibernate, grails, persistence, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

In **Grails 1.3.7** I've spent quite some time to convert my domain class relations according to Burt's suggestions in http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance

Now, **Grails 2** supports Hibernate's Bags and I am considering to revert my changes back to `hasMany`/`belongsTo`.

1. **With which option will I be more future-proof?**
2. **Which problems might arise if I stick to the manual/explicit implementation?**
3. **Which problems might arise if I switch to Bags?**
4. **Is there any advantage in either variant compared to the other?**

*Note that the application will see long-term improvements over many years (so no 'deploy-and-forget' :).*

UPDATE: One main concern is how much hassle it would incur *in regards to manual changes in the database* if I did the change *after* the app goes live. Currently it is unreleased, so it poses to be reasonable before Go-Live.

**UPDATE: THE ANSWER**

In the blogpost '[Hibernate Bags in Grails 2.0](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1029)' dated November 2011, Burt Beckwith describes issues with Bags in Grails 2 and concludes:

> So I guess I’m back to advocating the approach from my earlier talks;
>   don’t map a collection of Books in the Author class, but add an Author
>   field to the Book class instead

**So the answer is to stick with the converted (i.e. non-set/-list/-bag) variant.**

*Please vote for re-opening this thread so it may be answered & accepted in correct fashion.*

Comment: Your comment is ambiguous: 'already implemented' in the app (the old style) or 'already implemented' in the framework (new feature/style). Also, I'd be curious for reasons.

Comment: first of all, wait until grails 2.0 is really out